# gcloud deploy app does not automatically deploy index.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I used to deploy AppEngine apps with appcfg.py which, as far as I remember, was automatically deploying the index.yaml file as part of the app deployment.

Now that I'm using `gcloud app deploy` I've found out the hard way that I also have to run `gcloud app deploy index.yaml` to get the indices created.

Why was gcloud designed that way?

Comment: FWIW, even `appcfg.py update` wouldn't always update `index.yaml`. For example it stopped doing so for me once I added a 2nd module to my app). In such cases explicit `appcfg.py update_indexes` was required  - which was, after all, the official/documented index update method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After indexes are uploaded, it can take a few minutes for them to actually build.  While they build, any app that attempts to use those indexes will fail.  The behavior in `appcfg.py` of uploading both at the same time can actually result in apps failing for a few minutes while the indexes build.

The behavior in `gcloud app` is more explicit to avoid these issues. If you are adding new indexes and new code that depends on it, you should use this procedure:

```
gcloud app deploy index.yaml
# wait for indexes to build
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```